# Skorch: Help constructing classifier for multiple outputs

Tags: skorch

I am attempting to learn skorch by translating a simple pytorch model that predicts the 2 digits contained in a set of MNIST multi digit pictures. These pictures contain 2 overlapping digits which are the output lables (`y`). I am getting the following error:

`ValueError: Stratified CV requires explicitely passing a suitable y`

I followed the "MNIST with SciKit-Learn and skorch" notebook AND applied the multiple output fixes outlined in "Multiple return values from forward" by creating a custom `get_loss` function.

Data dimensions are:

- X: `(40000, 1, 4, 28)`
- y: `(40000, 2)`

Code:

```py
class Flatten(nn.Module):
    """A custom layer that views an input as 1D."""

    def forward(self, input):
        return input.view(input.size(0), -1)


class CNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 32, 3)
        self.pool1 = nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2))
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, 3)
        self.pool2 = nn.MaxPool2d((2, 2))
        self.flatten = Flatten()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2880, 64)
        self.drop1 = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(64, 10)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(64, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.pool1(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = self.pool2(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.drop1(x)
        out_first_digit = self.fc2(x)
        out_second_digit = self.fc3(x)

        return out_first_digit, out_second_digit


torch.manual_seed(0)

class CNN_net(NeuralNetClassifier):
    def get_loss(self, y_pred, y_true, *args, **kwargs):

        loss1 = F.cross_entropy(y_pred[0], y_true[:,0])
        loss2 = F.cross_entropy(y_pred[1], y_true[:,1])

        return 0.5 * (loss1 + loss2)

net = CNN_net(
    CNN,
    max_epochs=5,
    lr=0.1,
    device=device,
)

net.fit(X_train, y_train);
```

1. Do I need to modify the format of y?
2. Do I need to construct additional custom functions (predict)?
3. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

skorch's `NeuralNetClassifier` applies a stratified cross-validation split by default to provide you with metrics such as validation accuracy during training. Of course this makes it necessary that your data *can be split* that way. Since you have **two** labels for each image there is no trivial way to do a stratified split (although there [are ways](http://scikit.ml/stratification.html)).

Two solutions come to mind:

1. disable the train split altogether (pass `train_split=None`) and lose validation during training
2. change the train split to non-stratified by passing `train_split=skorch.dataset.CVSplit(5, stratified=False)`

Since I guess that you want validation metrics during training your final code should look like this:

```
net = CNN_net(
    CNN,
    max_epochs=5,
    lr=0.1,
    device=device,
    train_split=skorch.dataset.CVSplit(5, stratified=False),
)

net.fit(X_train, y_train);
```

Comment: Thank you for both the suggestions and additional reading.

I tried both solutions with the following results:
1. disabling split is successful. I was able to use the trained model's forward to predict results and compute accuracies
2. disabling stratification produced the following error:
`ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multiclass-multioutput and multiclass targets`

Is this implying that y_train needs to be reshaped?